# Is it possible to disable Swift documentation in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am not using Swift, so I don't need its documentation in Xcode. Currently it just messes with Objective C documentation.

Is it possible to disable Swift section of documentation in Xcode?

Comment: The online documentation can do this. It sure would be nice if the documentation in Xcode could do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is just a set of HTML files. If it's downloaded, you can edit a CSS file to completely hide Swift or Objective-C code.

1. Open Documentation window.
2. Select "Editor" > "Share" > "Open in Browser" menu.
3. Copy the corresponding part of the address of the page that opens up:

`/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.XXX.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/`

4. Switch to Finder, and use "Go" > "Go to Folder" menu to open up the folder.
5. Browse to `Resources/XXXX/CSS` folder and edit "xcode5.css" file. You should add either of these blocks to hide Swift or Objective-C:

```
div .Swift {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```
div .Objective-C {
    display: none !important;
}
```

6. Restart Xcode and enjoy reduced clutter.

Comment: @Kibernetik Pointum's instructions work in Xcode 6.3.1.  The CSS rules you added seem unnecessary _(Pointum's rules would have priority over them anyway)_, so I believe your issue is that you made a mistake in following the instructions.  Make sure there's a space between the `div` and the `.Swift`/ `.Objective-C`, and that the `!important` is present before the `;`, and that the rule you choose is added to the end of `xcode5.css` _(even when using Xcode 6.x)_.

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash) to address this and several other weaknesses in the Xcode doc browser. The current Mac Store version doesn't handle it quite right yet, but when the current beta (2.2) is approved, it'll let you choose which languages to display just as you suggest.

Comment: the excellent plug-in https://github.com/omz/Dash-Plugin-for-Xcode makes it seamless too.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible, and the idea of making it possible would be an excellent enhancement request in a bug report to Apple.