# Change the Quick Help documentation language in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode6

This may be an Xcode 6 bug, but some system methods when clicked or option-clicked reveal Quick Help documentation in Swift instead of Objective-C, which is the development language I'm using for this project.

Is there an Xcode setting somewhere that allows one to change which language to display in Quick Help? The Apple Release documentation says:

> Per-language documentation. The Xcode documentation viewer shows Quick
>   Help or reference documentation in the language of your
>   choice—Objective-C, Swift, or both.

Precisely how one goes about selecting which language to use is conveniently omitted.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-documentation_organizer/FindingandViewingDeveloperDocumentation/FindingandViewingDeveloperDocumentation.html) document "documentation viewer" is not exactly the same as Quick Help.

However, you can change its language. Check the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076713/is-it-possible-to-disable-swift-documentation-in-xcode) question.

It might also change the name of Quick Help documentation.

P.S. What you are experiencing is definitely a bug. If you select a method written in Objective-C its documentation in Quick Help should be in Objective-C. And if your method is written in Swift - documentation should be in Swift too.